# Better way to do pygame.rect.colliderect()

Tags: python, pygame

I have a platformer in pygame where a player can jump and move left/right. To test if the player is colliding with a platform, I use the pygame.rect.colliderect() function. The problem I am having is that when the player is on a block that kills him and a platform at the same time, if the killing block is to the left of the platform, he will die. If it is to the right of the platform, he will live. **I want to know if there is a better way to test collision or if I will have to make such a function myself.**

Player is pink, platform is white, death blocks are red. The player wont die in the first picture but will die in the second picture.

[image] , [image]

This is my current code:

```
class Player(Entity):
(other things in the Player class that are irrelevant)
def update(self):
    self.xvel = 0
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and self.onfloor: self.yvel = -2
    if keys[pygame.K_a]: self.xvel = -1
    if keys[pygame.K_s]: pass
    if keys[pygame.K_d]: self.xvel = 1
    if not self.onfloor and self.yvel < 10:
        self.yvel += .05
    self.move(self.xvel, 0)
    self.move(0, self.yvel)
def move(self, xvel, yvel):
    self.rect.x += xvel
    self.rect.y += yvel
    self.onfloor = False
    for thing in entities: # entities is a list of all entities, thing.rect is the pygame.rect.Rect instance for that entity
        if thing != self:
            if self.rect.colliderect(thing.rect):
                if isinstance(thing, End): self.won = True
                if isinstance(thing, Death): self.lost = True
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = thing.rect.bottom
                    self.yvel = 0
                if xvel < 0: self.rect.left = thing.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = thing.rect.top
                    self.onfloor = True
                if xvel > 0: self.rect.right = thing.rect.left
```

I tried making my own function but it didn't work. This is what I did:

```
def entitycollide(self, entity):
sx1, sx2, sy1, sy2 = self.rect.left, self.rect.right, self.rect.top, self.rect.bottom
ex1, ex2, ey1, ey2 = entity.rect.left, entity.rect.right, entity.rect.top, entity.rect.bottom
if ((sx1 < ex1 < sx2) or (sx1 < ex2 < sx2)) and ((sy1 < ey1 < sy2) or (sy1 < ey2 < sy2)):
    return True
else: return False
```

Comment: What would happen if there were a "death block" not adjacent to any platform?

Comment: If the player is on a death block not adjacent to a platform or on 2 death blocks, he would die.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is that you have to do two passes.  First collect all the objects that `colliderect` identifies (or all the ones whose `rect.top` values identify them as being under the player).  Then react to all the objects at once.

Here, it's probably sufficient to store the left-most block on which the player is standing (which may change as you consider more `entities`).  After considering all the candidates, react to the type of the saved block.

Comment: If I do get all entities that collide with the player after he moves, the player will die if he runs into a wall and a death block at the same time, which is weird. I will just fix it by saying if the player is running into a platform and death block at the same time, it does not die.

Comment: Maybe if `self.lost == True and (something to check if it has collided with a platform in the same direction): self.lost = False`

Comment: @SnootierBaBoon: I already said that you might want to consider only the ones under the player.  As for resetting `self.lost`, think instead about never setting it incorrectly (something like `if nDeath and not nPlatform: self.lost=True`) to avoid silly things like "You can survive with 0 HP if you're touching a wall.".